# In jquery form validation ajax not responding

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

I am trying to validate my code with jquery. Its working but when it come to ajax it not loading any page. Rather my path is wrong or something other. Please help me to solve this.

this is my view file

**admin_view.php**

```
<?php include('assets/header.php'); ?> 

<div class="container">
    <h1>Welcome to Admin Login</h1>
    <?if($this->session->flashdata('flashError')):?>
    <p class='flashMsg flashError'> 
        <?= $this->session->flashdata('flashError') ?> </p>
    <?endif?>
    <!-- new line inserted -->
    <form method="post" name="myForm" accept-charset="utf-8"   class="login" id="form" >
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-xs-4">
                <!--<label for="admin">Admin</label>
                <input type="text" name="admin" class="form-control" id="admin" value=""  placeholder="admin name" />-->
                Admin Name: <input type="text" name="admin" id="admin" class="form-control"  value="<?php echo set_value('admin'); ?>"  placeholder="admin name" >
                <?php echo form_error("admin"); ?>
                <p id='p1'></p>
                <br>
                <!--  <label for="password">password</label>
                 <input type="text" name="password" class="form-control" id="password" value=""  placeholder="password" required/>
                -->
                Admin Password: <input type="password" name="password" id="password" class="form-control" value=""  placeholder="password" >
                <?php echo form_error("password"); ?>
                <p id='p2'></p>
                <br>
                <br>
                <input type="button" name="submit" value="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-primary"  >
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="error"></div>
    </form> 
</div>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#submit").click(function () {
            var admin = $("#admin").val();
            var password = $("#password").val();

            $("#returnmessage").empty(); // To empty previous error/success message.
            // Checking for blank fields.
            if (admin == '')
            {
                $('div.error').html("Please Fill Admin Required Fields");
            } else if (password == '')
            {
                $('div.error').html("Please Fill Password Required Fields");
            } else
            {//alert('hello world');
                // Returns successful data submission message when the entered information is stored in database.
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "<?php base_url() ?>index.php/admin_login/login",
                    data: {"admin": admin, "password": password},
                    dataType: "json"

                }).done(function (data) {
                    if (data.error != "")
                    {
                        //alert('hello if');
                        $('div.error').html(data.error);
                    } else
                    {

                       // alert('hello else');
                        window.location.href="admin_view";
                    }

                });
            }
        });
    });
</script>


<?php include('assets/footer.php'); ?>
```

Comment: "Rather my path is wrong or something other" — You've shown us the PHP that generates the path. So now tell us what the output of that PHP is (when you view the source in the browser) and what the path should be.

Comment: i do not know if ajax's url parameter can have php code for it, but the last php opening tag ain't got closing one...

Comment: try this : `url: "<?php echo base_url() ?>index.php/admin_login/login"`

Comment: Have you tried `url: <?php echo base_url('admin_login/login') ?>` You definitely need the `echo` in that PHP Syntax. So either this or @Ranjith version should work

Comment: Either way, check what is actually being received by the browser by looking at either `page source` or use the browsers debugger to view that actual value being generated out of this part of your script

Comment: @RiggsFolly i just check code via fire bug, it goes correct but not rediect on page

Answer (score 0):

You have provide wrong path to ajax url,

```
url: "<?php base_url() ?>index.php/admin_login/login"
```

this statement will not works directly, because `<?php base_url() ?>` is a php statement and you are using this in javascript, this is not acceptable.

use like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">var path= "<?php echo base_url();?>";</script>
```

Write this statement in your head section,this statement will define your base url to path variable, which is a javascript variable and you can use it in your javascript code.

then append url like:

```
url: path+"/index.php/admin_login/login",
```

hope this will help to you.

Comment: That whole piece of javascript is being generated by PHP in its entirety so this is all being run under PHP